# how to integrate apache ofbiz in liferay using soap

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, liferay

I'm trying to create a Web Service in Eclipse Java EE IDE (Indigo Service Release 2, Windows 7 32-bit) based on a WSDL file in liferay , but when I click "finish" in the creation wizard I always get:

IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.makeFolderPathAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:790)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.makeFolderPathAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:833)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.createFileAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:765)
  at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.utils.ContentCopyUtils.copyDirectoryRecursivelyIntoWorkspace(ContentCopyUtils.java:111)
  at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientTestCaseIntegrateCommand.CopyJUnitJarToProject(Axis2ClientTestCaseIntegrateCommand.java:138)
  at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientTestCaseIntegrateCommand.execute(Axis2ClientTestCaseIntegrateCommand.java:73)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
  at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:257)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:277)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the error stack

```
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.makeFolderPathAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:790)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.makeFolderPathAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:833)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.common.FileResourceUtils.createFileAtLocation(FileResourceUtils.java:765)
```

It looks like there might be some discrepancy in creating a file/folder.
Check to see if the provided folder location exists.
If yes, then check to see if eclipse has enough permissions to create/write files/folder to the specified path.